# Is there a functional difference between these 2 snippets of my code? Does the second one handle possible errors the same way as the first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I asked a question on stack overflow earlier, and a kind user suggested some improvements for my code which seemed great, so I started going over my code in order to implement these changes. The problem is that I'm not sure if my reworked code is handling possible errors the same way as the first.

Here's my current code right now:

```
module.exports.deleteBrand = async (req, res, next) => {
    let brandId = req.body.brandId
    let brand

    try {
        brand = await Brand.destroy({
            where: {
                id: brandId
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

    if (brand) {
        res.status(200).json({
            brand: brand
        })
    } else {
        res.status(500)
    }
}
```

And this is how I intend to rework it:

```
module.exports.deleteBrand = async (req, res, next) => {
    let brandId = req.body.brandId

    try {
        let brand = await Brand.destroy({
            where: {
                id: brandId
            }
        })

        res.status(200).json({
            brand: brand
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500)
    }
}
```

As you can see, in my first code snippet, the `try-catch` block surrounds only my database query and then I check if the database query was successful outside the `try-catch`, and only send the `200 status` response if it is. Otherwise, I send a `500 status`.

Is my `if-else` useless in that scenario, considering that if the database query fails, the error would be caught by the catch block? Should the code that returns 500 status be placed in the catch block?

Comment: i don't see any need for additional if,else, just try catch is enough

Comment: How about 400 (invalid ID), 404 (id not found), 403 (no access) and other possible REST errors? How do you plan to handle these?

Comment: @georg Well I also have a middleware that handles errors for when the user is not authenticated or has an invalid token, but other than that, I don't have anything else. Error handling seems like such a broad subject and there are so many possible errors which I might not even be able to foresee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small difference in error handling, yes, but if anything it seems likely to be an improvement. The difference is:

- In your first example, an error raised by `res.status(200).json({brand: brand})` after successfully retrieving `brand` from the database is not caught and terminates `deleteBrand`.
- In your second example, that error is caught and results in calling the `res.status(500)` in the `catch` block.

`json({brand: brand})` might throw an error if `brand` has any circular references and so can't be converted to JSON. In that case, your `res.status(500)` will overwrite your previous `res.status(200)` (assuming response headers haven't been sent yet, which is probably a correct assumption).

---

Side note: You're using ES2015+ code, which means you can use shorthand property notation and change `.json({brand: brand})` to simply `.json({brand})`.